# scipy.sparse.diags: ValueError: Different number of diagonals and offsets

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the task of calculating PPMI.

PPMI is (10,000 by 10,000). sum_of_all_cols is (1 by 10,000) sum_of_all_rows is (10,000 by 1). I don't understand why the diags function won't accept it. This is the output of joint_probabilities_cols

matrix([[5.5433802e-02, 5.1464140e-02, 5.1569015e-02, ..., 6.5132836e-06,
         6.5139061e-06, 6.5548675e-06]], dtype=float32)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
import scipy
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, diags
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: {} output_filename".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

# here are a few helper functions you might find useful...
def multiply_by_rows(matrix, coefficients):
    diag = diags(coefficients, 0)
    return diag * matrix

def multiply_by_columns(matrix, coefficients):
    diag = diags(coefficients, 0)
    return matrix * diag

print("Loading cooccurrence matrix...")
with np.load("cooccur.npz") as loader:
    PPMI = csr_matrix((loader['data'], loader['indices'],
        loader['indptr']), shape=loader['shape'])

print("Computing PPMI...")

##### FILL IN THE CODE HERE #####
# you should compute the PMI matrix and save it into the PPMI variable.
# Hint: the following functions/attributes might be useful:
#
# - csr_matrix.sum()
# - csr_matrix.data
# - array.sum()
# - np.reciprocal()
# - np.log2()
# - multiply_by_rows() (above)
# - multiply_by_columns() (above)

# Refer to page 16 of chapter word embeddings
sum_of_all_values = csr_matrix.sum(PPMI)
sum_of_all_cols   = np.sum(PPMI,axis=0)
sum_of_all_rows   = np.sum(PPMI,axis=1) 


joint_probabilities = PPMI / sum_of_all_values
joint_probabilities_cols = sum_of_all_cols / sum_of_all_values
joint_probabilities_rows = sum_of_all_rows / sum_of_all_values


tmp = multiply_by_rows(joint_probabilities, np.reciprocal(joint_probabilities_rows))
tmp = multiply_by_columns(tmp , np.reciprocal(joint_probabilities_cols))


PPMI = np.log2(tmp)

##### STOP FILLING IN THE CODE HERE

# At this point, PPMI is actually PMI, so let's drop all negative values,
# sparsify, and then compute rank-50 SVD

# PPMI = max(0, PMI)
PPMI.data[PPMI.data < 0] = 0
# sparisfy
PPMI.eliminate_zeros()

print("Computing SVD...")
u, s, vt = svds(PPMI, k = 50)

p = 1
emb = u * (s ** p)

# normalize embeddings to unit length so cos(x, y) == x.T * y
emb = (emb.T / norm(emb, axis=1, ord=2)).T

print("Saving embeddings...")
np.save(sys.argv[1], emb)
print("Done!")
```

I get the following error. I cannot make sense of it. Please help.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5fa1bb552eaa> in <module>()
     29 
     30 
---> 31 tmp = multiply_by_rows(joint_probabilities, np.reciprocal(joint_probabilities_rows))
     32 tmp = multiply_by_columns(tmp , np.reciprocal(joint_probabilities_cols))
     33 #tmp1 = np.divide(joint_probabilities, joint_probabilities_rows)

<ipython-input-6-476e6bafddc2> in multiply_by_rows(matrix, coefficients)
      1 # here are a few helper functions you might find useful...
      2 def multiply_by_rows(matrix, coefficients):
----> 3     diag = diags(coefficients, 0)
      4     return diag * matrix
      5 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py in diags(diagonals, offsets, shape, format, dtype)
    140             diagonals = [np.atleast_1d(diagonals)]
    141         else:
--> 142             raise ValueError("Different number of diagonals and offsets.")
    143     else:
    144         diagonals = list(map(np.atleast_1d, diagonals))

ValueError: Different number of diagonals and offsets.
```

I've tried other approaches like this, but I get a memory error in those.

```
I  = np.eye(10000)
IC = np.divide(I, joint_probabilities_cols)
IR = np.divide(I, joint_probabilities_rows)
tmp3 = IR * joint_probabilities
tmp3 = tmp3 * IC
```

Comment: How many `diagonals` and `offsets` do you provide?  Have you experimented with the documented examples?  Read and understood the documentation?

Comment: @hpaulij like I specified the dimension in the beginning, (1, 10000) and (10000, 1). Offset 0 is given and that part is written by someone else and should not be edited.

Answer (score 0):

The input variable to diags can not be a matrix but needs to be array-like.

```
np.squeeze(np.asarray(joint_probabilities_cols))
```

This solves this problem.